# Can I use an sd card as internal storage with android 8.0

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a Samsung galaxy s7 with android 8.0. I've put a 64gb microsd in it. I wanted to use the card to store apps on but it's not working.

I'm trying to move a game of about 11gb on to the card but the transfer gets to 77% then tells me there's not enough storage space. I have 50gb+ space free on the card.

I've checked the card for faults using Windows and it says it's fine.

The only form of formatting available, using my phone, is portable storage. I've read that certain versions of android prevent or restrict the use of sd cards.

Is this what the problem is? Is there a way around it without rooting my phone?

Comment: You should format it in Android. Very likely it came formatted as FAT32 and that old file system has a file size limitation.

Comment: No. except for root solutions

Comment: AFAIK, it's not an issue with the Android version, but with [Samsung disabling adoptable storage since Galaxy S7](https://www.samsung.com/nz/support/mobile-devices/does-galaxy-s9-series-support-the-adoptable-storage-feature/).

Comment: Thanks. It's seems I'm stuck with low memory then. Unless I pay out for a new phone, funny how that works.